# If all eigenvalues of a matrix $A \in \Bbb{R}^{nxn}$ are real, then I can choose each eigenvector so that is not purely complex.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A \in \Bbb{R}^{n\times n}$. I was trying to reduce to an absurd (i.e. suppose always $v \in \Bbb{C}^{n}$) but I think I am not getting anywhere.

Comment: If the eigenvalue is real, the corresponding eigenvectors are solutions to a system of linear equations with real coefficients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then the eigenvectors for $\lambda$ are the solutions to the linear system $(A-\lambda I)v=0$. This is a system consisting only of real entries, so the solutions will always be real. This can be seen for instance by finding the solutions via row reduction.

Comment: mmm...."This is a system consisting only of real entries, so the solutions will always be real", but for example $$
    \begin{matrix}
    2 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$ is a matrix with real values and I think I can choose a complex solution for $Av = 0$

Comment: As my answer says, the system is *linear*.

Comment: Oh, I see...you're right, it's not the right counterexample. However, can you facilitate some demonstration or link to the property in question? I can't seem to find and I would be greatful. PS: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: It's basic linear algebra. You can always row-reduce your matrix until you get a reduced row echelon form, and from there solve explicitly. All operations are field operations so they will stay within the reals.